# Sequelize - an attribute, without corresponding table column is needed

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Suppose I have a `User` model and a table named `users` will be created based on that model.

I define its fields as follows.

```
User.init({
   username: {....}, 
   password: {....}
}, {sequelize, modelName: 'user'});
```

Let's suppose that I ask user to confirm their password (a very common practice), and want to validate if those two fields (`password` and `cpassword`) are identical, and I want to do it as part of Model validation using Model-wide validation, so my model will become something like this.

```
User.init({
   username: {....}, 
   password: {....}, 
   cpassword: {...},
   validate: {
     checkIfEqual() {
      if (cpassword !=== password) throw new Error("not same")
     }
   }
}, {sequelize, modelName: 'user'});
```

**BUT** Obviously I don't want to have the column cpassword in the users table.

I can check it manually, before calling User.Create, but I'd like to have that check as part of overall User model validation.

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `VIRTUAL` attributes. They're not stored inside your table but you can use them in your `models`.

And I found great example on [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/data-types.js~VIRTUAL.html). Please check that out.